# How to orient color scheme along z axis in R persp function?

Tags: r, colors

I have a matrix called ht2. I use `persp` function to generate a 3D view.

```
ht2 <- matrix(1, 29, 36)
ht2[4:26,4:33] <- 0
ht2[6:10,6:31] <- 3
ht2[13:17,6:31] <- 3
ht2[20:24,6:31] <- 3

persp(ht2, expand=0.03, theta=25, phi=25, shade=0.75, col=terrain.colors(999,alpha=1))
```

This gives me: 
[image: Current Plot]

As you can see, the color from green to yellow to brown changes along y-axis. However, I'd rather want to change it along z-axis.

I'm looking for any simple way to do that.

Comment: Maybe add the `ht2` matrix too?

Answer (score 2):

I found a possible solution in this site:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2003-July/036151.html

```
  levelpersp <- function(x, y, z, colors=topo.colors, ...) {
  ## getting the value of the midpoint
  zz <- (z[-1,-1] + z[-1,-ncol(z)] + z[-nrow(z),-1] + z[-nrow(z),-ncol(z)])/4
  ## calculating the breaks
  breaks <- hist(zz, plot=FALSE)$breaks
  ## cutting up zz
  cols <- colors(length(breaks)-1)
  zzz <- cut(zz, breaks=breaks, labels=cols)
  ## plotting
  persp(x, y, z, col=as.character(zzz), ...)
  ## return breaks and colors for the legend
  list(breaks=breaks, colors=cols)
  }


## Example
x <- seq(-10, 10, length=60)
y <- x
f <- function(x,y) { r <- sqrt(x^2+y^2); 10 * sin(r)/r }
z <- outer(x, y, f)
levelpersp(x, y, z, theta = 30, phi = 30, expand = 0.5)
```

Someone may suggest a way to implement this in original question.

Comment: looks like a good solution, cant you just plug in your values?

Comment: I tried, but failed. Like I said, I'm a beginner in R. I don't understand 90% of the code above.

Comment: oh no worries, you just need to plug in `x=1:nrow(ht2); y=1:ncol(ht2); z=ht2` and then the rest of your options into `levelpersp`

Comment: @bunk thanks, it worked. I'll try to perfect the rest on my own. I'd appreciate it if you have a quick idea how to invert the colors (green for bigger z value) without having to create new color palette.

Comment: if just change the `cols<-` line to `cols <- rev(colors(length(breaks)-1))` it should work.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you just have to give col= a matrix with your colours you want to fill the squares with, as simple example:

```
col=terrain.colors(max(ht2)+1)[ht2[-1,-1]+1]
```

(this simple version works since ht2 contains integers, otherwise it wouldn't)
This creates all the colours needed: terrain.colours(max(ht2)+1)
and then selects them for each position based on one corner: [ht2[-1,-1]+1]

What Anuj Sharma's answer does is basically a nicer version of this, it assumes you have decimal numbers, so it bins them (breaks & cutting up) and instead of taking one corner it uses the height of the middle point (averaging of the four shifted matrices in getting the midpoint )